# Android Studio SearchView filter in my app's Recycler View problem

Tags: java, android-studio, filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

The Create, Read, Write, Update and Delete function works but when I try to add the searchview that filters recyclerView, my app closes. I know there must be something missing like in dependencies, also checked the manifest, but for sure the code to execute the search filter is the problem (comment block 
     here are the code I tried to execute search filter in the VIewlist activity)

```
**The inputs are saved using sqlite, thanks guys
```

heres the logcat

[image]

heres the logcat2

[image]

line189
[image]

line202
[image]
    heres the code

```
The main activity just directs the user in/ Onclick listener to add record activity and view list activity using buttons*/


////////////////////////////////////////////PersonDbHelper/////////////////////////////////////////////////


package info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.Utils;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.model.Person;


public class PersonDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "people.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3 ;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "People";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_AGE = "age";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NUMBER = "number";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_LEFT = "lft";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_RIGHT = "rght";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_PAYMENT = "payment";


    public PersonDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PERSON_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_PERSON_AGE + " NUMBER NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PERSON_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_PERSON_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PERSON_NUMBER + " NUMBER NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_PERSON_LEFT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PERSON_RIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_PERSON_PAYMENT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // you can implement here migration process
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
    /**create record**/
    public void saveNewPerson(Person person) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME, person.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_AGE, person.getAge());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_DATE, person.getDate());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_ADDRESS, person.getAddress());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_NUMBER, person.getContactnumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_LEFT, person.getLefteyegrade());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_RIGHT, person.getRighteyegrade());
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_PAYMENT, person.getPayment());
        // insert
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /**Query records, give options to filter results**/
    public List<Person> peopleList(String filter) {
        String query;
        if(filter.equals("")){
            //regular query
            query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        }else{
            //filter results by filter option provided
            query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY "+ filter;
        }

        List<Person> personLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Person person;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                person = new Person();

                person.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
                person.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME)));
                person.setAge(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_AGE)));
                person.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_DATE)));

                personLinkedList.add(person);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return personLinkedList;
    }

    /**Query only 1 record**/
    public Person getPerson(long id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _id="+ id;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        Person receivedPerson = new Person();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            receivedPerson.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME)));
            receivedPerson.setAge(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_AGE)));
            receivedPerson.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_DATE)));
            receivedPerson.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_ADDRESS)));
            receivedPerson.setContactnumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_NUMBER)));
            receivedPerson.setLefteyegrade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_LEFT)));
            receivedPerson.setRighteyegrade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_RIGHT)));
            receivedPerson.setPayment(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_PAYMENT)));

        }
        return receivedPerson;
    }


    /**delete record**/
    public void deletePersonRecord(long id, Context context) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE _id='"+id+"'");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    /**update record**/
    public void updatePersonRecord(long personId, Context context, Person updatedperson) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //you can use the constants above instead of typing the column names
        db.execSQL("UPDATE  "+TABLE_NAME+" SET name ='"+ updatedperson.getName() + "', age ='" + updatedperson.getAge()+ "', date ='"+ updatedperson.getDate() + "', address ='"+ updatedperson.getAddress()+ "', number ='"+ updatedperson.getContactnumber()+ "', lft ='"+ updatedperson.getLefteyegrade()+ "', rght ='"+ updatedperson.getRighteyegrade()+ "', payment ='"+ updatedperson.getPayment()+ "'  WHERE _id='" + personId + "'");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }




}


////////////////////////////////////////////////Person Adapter////////////////////////////////////////////////

package info.glinogaprdrecrds.recrdapp.Utils;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.R;
import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.UpdateRecordActivity;
import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.Utils.PersonDBHelper;
import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.model.Person;

public class PersonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Person> mPeopleList;
    private List<Person> exampleListFull;
    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerV;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView personNameTxtV;
        public TextView personAgeTxtV;
        public TextView personDateTxtV;



        public View layout;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            personNameTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            personAgeTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.age);
            personDateTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);

        }


    }

        public PersonAdapter(List<Person> mPeopleList){
        this.mPeopleList = mPeopleList;
        exampleListFull = new ArrayList<>(mPeopleList);
    }

    public void add(int position, Person person) {
        mPeopleList.add(position, person);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mPeopleList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }



    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public PersonAdapter(List<Person> myDataset, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mPeopleList = myDataset;
        mContext = context;
        mRecyclerV = recyclerView;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public PersonAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext());
        View v =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        final Person person = mPeopleList.get(position);
        holder.personNameTxtV.setText("Name: " + person.getName());
        holder.personAgeTxtV.setText("Age: " + person.getAge());
        holder.personDateTxtV.setText("Date: " + person.getDate());

        //listen to single view layout click
        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setTitle("Choose option");
                builder.setMessage("Update or delete user?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //go to update activity
                        goToUpdateActivity(person.getId());

                    }
                });
                builder.setNeutralButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PersonDBHelper dbHelper = new PersonDBHelper(mContext);
                        dbHelper.deletePersonRecord(person.getId(), mContext);

                        mPeopleList.remove(position);
                        mRecyclerV.removeViewAt(position);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mPeopleList.size());
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });


    }

    private void goToUpdateActivity(long personId){
        Intent goToUpdate = new Intent(mContext, UpdateRecordActivity.class);
        goToUpdate.putExtra("USER_ID", personId);
        mContext.startActivity(goToUpdate);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPeopleList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        return exampleFilter;
    }

    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            List<Person> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length()==0){
                filteredList.addAll(exampleListFull);
            }else{
                String filterPatern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (Person item : exampleListFull){
                    if(item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPatern)){
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return  results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            mPeopleList.clear();
            mPeopleList.addAll((List)filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////ViewList////////////////////////////////////////////////

package info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.List;

import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.Utils.PersonDBHelper;
import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.model.Person;
import info.glinogaprdrecrds.recrdapp.Utils.PersonAdapter;

public class viewList extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private PersonDBHelper dbHelper;
    private PersonAdapter adapter;
    private String filter = "";
    private List<Person> exampleList;
    private SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_list);


        //initialize the variables
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        populaterecyclerView(filter);


    }

    private void populaterecyclerView(String filter){
        dbHelper = new PersonDBHelper(this);
        adapter = new PersonAdapter(dbHelper.peopleList(filter), this, mRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;

    }

     */
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////UpdateRecordActivity//////////////////////////////////////


package info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.Utils.PersonDBHelper;
import info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.model.Person;

public class UpdateRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNameEditText;
    private EditText mAgeEditText;
    private EditText mAddressEditText;
    private EditText mDateEditText;
    private EditText mContactNumberText;
    private EditText mLeftEyeGradeEditText;
    private EditText mRightEyeGradeEditText;
    private EditText mPaymentEditText;
    private Button UpdateUser;

    private PersonDBHelper dbHelper;
    private long receivedPersonId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_record);

        mNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.userNameUpdate);
        mAgeEditText = findViewById(R.id.userAgeUpdate);
        mAddressEditText = findViewById(R.id.userAddressUpdate);
        mDateEditText = findViewById(R.id.userDateUpdate);
        mContactNumberText = findViewById(R.id.userContactNumberUpdate);
        mLeftEyeGradeEditText = findViewById(R.id.userLeftEyeGradeUpdate);
        mRightEyeGradeEditText = findViewById(R.id.userRightEyeGradeUpdate);
        mPaymentEditText = findViewById(R.id.userPaymentUpdate);
        UpdateUser = findViewById(R.id.UpdateUser);

        dbHelper = new PersonDBHelper(this);



        try {
            //get intent to get person id
            receivedPersonId = getIntent().getLongExtra("USER_ID", 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /***populate user data before update***/
        Person queriedPerson = dbHelper.getPerson(receivedPersonId);
        //set field to this user data
        mNameEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getName());
        mAgeEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getAge());
        mAddressEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getAddress());
        mDateEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getDate());
        mContactNumberText.setText(queriedPerson.getContactnumber());
        mLeftEyeGradeEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getLefteyegrade());
        mRightEyeGradeEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getRighteyegrade());
        mPaymentEditText.setText(queriedPerson.getPayment());




        //listen to add button click to update
        UpdateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //call the save person method
                updateUser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateUser(){

        String name = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String age = mAgeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String address = mAddressEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String date = mDateEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String contactnumber = mContactNumberText.getText().toString().trim();
        String lefteyegrade =  mLeftEyeGradeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String righteyegrade = mRightEyeGradeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String payment = mPaymentEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if(name.isEmpty() && age.isEmpty()&& address.isEmpty()&& date.isEmpty()&& contactnumber.isEmpty()&& lefteyegrade.isEmpty()&& righteyegrade.isEmpty()&& payment.isEmpty() ){
            Toast.makeText(this,"You must fill up all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Person updatedPersonRecord = new Person(name, age, address, date, contactnumber, lefteyegrade, righteyegrade, payment);
        dbHelper.updatePersonRecord(receivedPersonId, this, updatedPersonRecord);
        gotolist();
    }

    private void gotolist(){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, info.codestart.glinogaprdrecrds.MainActivity.class));
    }

}   

//I modified this code to add more user inputs and some layout  from the original template that I followed in youtube tutorials
```

Comment: you app closes i think you mean it crashes if it is correct then can you please share the logcat

Comment: Asyu i saw your error , your search view in the menu xml and  and your searchView in the code are different .

Comment: Asyu i saw your error , your search view from menu xml is different from the one you used in the code , one is from support library and other is from android sdk you should use same in xml also in code

Comment: thanks sir, now the searchview appear but I get an error, view the logcat2 screenshot

Comment: can you show me which is line number 189 in the PersonAdapter class , also the following link should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it   null pointer exceptions are very common and very easy to fix

Comment: make sure all of item, item.getName() , filterPattern are not null, you can check by logging

Comment: and luck and consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in case you have question next time

Answer (score 0):

I used this method and working fine...

This is my code in recyclerView

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filefilter;
}

private Filter filefilter=new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        ArrayList<String> flist=new ArrayList<>();
        if (charSequence==null || charSequence.length()==0){
            flist.addAll(list2);
        }else {
            String filterpattren=charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (String item : list2) {
                if (item.toLowerCase().contains(filterpattren)) {
                    flist.add(item);
                }
            }



        }
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        results.values=flist;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        mlist.clear();
        mlist.addAll((List)filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

This is code for making list2 in recyclerview constructor

```
ArrayList<String> mlist=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
Context context;



public MylistAdapter2(ArrayList<String> mlist,Context context){
    this.mlist=mlist;
    list2=new ArrayList<>(mlist);
    this.context=context;
}
```

And this is code in onCreateOptionMenu where i calling getfilter method in recyclerview

```
    SearchView searchView=(SearchView) searchItem .getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            ProfileFragment.mylistAdapter2.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is code in profile fragment

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

static RecyclerView recyclerView;
static RelativeLayout emergency_layout;
static MylistAdapter2 mylistAdapter2;
static ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<>();
String val=MainActivity.FOLDER_NAME;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
static TextView emergency_msg;
GetData obj=new GetData(MainActivity.sharedPreferences);

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);

    swipeRefreshLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout2);
    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    emergency_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.emergency_layout);
    emergency_msg=view.findViewById(R.id.emergency_text);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mylistAdapter2=new MylistAdapter2(getchildfiles(),getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mylistAdapter2);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            MainActivity.mylist.clear();
            mylist.clear();
            new sub_task().execute(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        }
    });

    return view;
}
public ArrayList<String> getchildfiles(){
    mylist.clear();
    if(TextUtils.equals(val,"All Documents")){
        for (int i=0;i<MainActivity.mylist.size();i++){
            mylist.add(MainActivity.mylist.get(i).getName());
        }
    }else{
        for (int i=0;i<MainActivity.mylist.size();i++){
            if (TextUtils.equals(val,MainActivity.mylist.get(i).getParentFile().getName())){
                mylist.add(MainActivity.mylist.get(i).getName());
            }
        }
    }
    return mylist;
}



public class sub_task extends AsyncTask<File,String,String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... files) {
        obj.getdoc(files[0]);
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        obj.savedata();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        MylistAdapter2 mylistAdapter=new MylistAdapter2(getchildfiles(),getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mylistAdapter);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: sir ALI RAZA whats your ProfileFragment for?

Comment: thanks sir but still my app crashes when i try to add the onCreateOptionMenu

Comment: @Asyu: Actually i send data from profile fragment to recyclerview adapter,but my search bar in activity where i cannot create the new object of recyclerview adapter because i have to use only one object of recyclerview adabter for sending data and calling getfilter function,,,for this i made recyclerview adapter static.... i hope ;you understand

Comment: make sure your code is this in menu.xml    `    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        />
`

Comment: yes sir, its in menu.xml, i will try to make it static since thats the suggestion the ide says

Comment: sir @ALI RIZA can you show me sir  the code on how you create the ProfileFragment in the onCreateOptionMenu cause i dont have matching variable to execute that on my code

Comment: sirrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr, Im really happy to say for the both of you who help and make me realize the errors i made in the code now the functions worked and now adding designs and some animations in the app, Real Thanks sir ALI RIZA

Comment: @Asyu: I am very glad to assist you and you found your soloution